# Automator Service for Notes + Calendar

Tags: macos, scripting, calendar, automator

I've been trying to figure this out for a while. Is there a way to set up a service that would parse a Note and create calendar events based on each line from that Note?

For example, say that the contents of my note are as follows:

```
December 1 9:00AM - 5:00PM
December 2 9:00AM - 5:00PM
December 3 11:30AM - 8:00PM
```

Is anyone familiar with how to parse this? I'd like to set up a service that would take those dates, and those hours and create calendar events with a default name (ex. "Work"). I'm familiar with how to do it in programming languages like Python or Swift, but I'm still new to scripting.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!